# Arduino and Pointers to char array

Tags: c, pointers, arduino

Need to get a pointer to a char array variable.

```
  char hostName[] = "Server1";
  uint32_t *p;
  p = &hostName;
```

My understanding is probably lacking seriously, but I cant figure it out. I get the following error on the "p = &hostName;" line.

```
invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'uint32_t* {aka long unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]
```

Can anyone help please.

Comment: The error message does not match the code. The code you show would get an error message about conversion from `char (*)[8]`, not `int*`. Did you paste an error message from a different experiment than the code shown?

Comment: Actually this isn't relate to Arduino.

Comment: Arduino language is a flavour of C++

Comment: @Eric. Definitely an Arduino project, no mistakes made with respect to project and error message. Also, running Arduino Nano33 IoT. But that should not make a difference right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char hostname[] = "Server1;` declares `hostName` to be an array of `char`. So `&hostname` is a pointer to an array of `char`.

`uint32_t *p;` defines `p` to be a pointer to a `uint32_t`.

A pointer to a an array of `char` and a pointer to a `uint32_t` are different things, and they are incompatible types. C does not allow you to assign one to the other.

You can force the conversion using a cast, and the compiler will accept it. But that raises issues about good programming and portability, and you should not do it at this stage of learning C.

To get a pointer to the array, you could use `char (*p)[]; p = &hostName;` or `char (*p)[8]; p = &hostName;`.

However, it is likely you actually want a pointer to the first character in the array, in which case you can use:

```
char *p;
p = &hostName[0];
```

Also, when an array is used in an expression, but not as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so you can also use:

```
char *p;
p = hostName;
```

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks, fixed. It was intended to be `char (*p)[];`.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thank you for the suggestion!!! char (*p)[]; p = &hostName does not work and returns the following error message: cannot convert 'char (*)[8]' to 'char (*)[]' in assignment. The second suggestion does compile however; char (*p)[8]; p = &hostName; But I am running into different issues when passing the pointer into a library function.

Comment: First of all, You should understand the easy solution: `char* p = hostName;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from your understanding, if we write the variable with &(ampersand) operator, it will gives the address( that is number). When you print the address, it will be like a unsigned integer.So according to that, You are trying to declare unsigned integer pointer and then assign the address with them.
`uint32_t *p;
p = &hostName;`
But this won't makes sense. Because FYI, Pointers are basically store the address of the variables with the same type.`p = &hostName` This is completely wrong. when doing this, assigns the sequences of character into unsigned integer pointer.
Hope this might helps:)